# How to hide parameter in routes.MapRoute (mvc3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello Everybody i'm a problem about custom (routes.MapRoute) in mvc3.

i has been custom my  (routes.MapRoute) code here

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "stock-detail1",
            "used-cars-for-sale",
           //  "{action}", auto call method in controller
            new { 
                controller = "Stock", 
                action = "Detail"
            }
        );
```

and this my link   string sUrlDetail1 = Url.RouteUrl("stock-detail1", new { abc="123" });
i have pass parameter  mycontroller, but i don't want show parameter  in link as follows (abc/used-cars-for-sale/?abc=123)
Please hepl me thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as your parameters are on the client, they are never 'hidden' unless you encrypt them. You could store the parameter in a hidden field and set the action method to post, then the value is not visible in the URL. But a user with a little bit of knowlegde about web could still manipulate the hidden field (unless you encrypt the value in some way).

Edit : one thing you can do is Url rewritting https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/